# Count Unique Email Addresses In Report

Tags: reporting, administration, leads

Along the lines of **a previous question** that was solved:  [Counting parent records in parent-child report](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/8029/counting-parent-records-in-parent-child-report)

I am trying to produce a report which currently is Matrix, is grouped by Email Address on the left (looking at Duplicates by email address essentially) and I want to count the Email Addresses (**ONE per address, not one per RECORD**).

Any ideas?  I've tried variations of the previous solution, but it was for a parent-child report.  This is just a single-table report (Lead in this case).

[image]

Comment: Not sure I understand your question.  An instance of an email address would be an instance of a record with that address. Can you clarify? EDIT: I think I get it now... what is your end goal, to have a count of unique leads or to send an email?

Comment: To get a count of unique email addresses within the report.   John@Doe.com may have TEN LEADS, but his email address will count as ONE when summarized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm fairly certain that there isn't a reporting-based solution here. In the unique parent-child report, the formula was only counted once because there was only one parent record.  In this scenario however, there are multiple lead records and I suspect the formula field is being counted up multiple times, one for each lead record, which doesn't help find unique email dupes.

You have a few code-based options to address this.  One would be to add all of these leads to a campaign and have a VF page that removes email dupes.  You could then report on those campaign members.  Another would be a batch apex job that marks a field on all but one lead as being a duplicate email. A third solution would be to create a parent object of lead and a batch apex job that parents dupes to the same object based on email match.  Honestly, these all seem like overkill solutions but I can't think of a declarative way to achieve this.

Comment: I actually previously wrote (and have in play) a trigger system that marks any non-first instance of an Email Address on leads as "Duplicate" (so that the first one is not marked, and the rest are)... but it works, I'll say, 98% of the time.  I eventually need to go back and figure out the shortcomings, which likely stem from (1) me not handling Deletions well and (2) possibly other holes.